# How to make a table connecting two variables and an output in a separate sheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I have a semi-complex sheet in Excel that takes assumptions about usage, visitors etc to forecast the sales for the month. I want to make a table, in a new sheet, using different ranges of two variables so I can see which combination produces least/most sales.
Something like this:

[image: What I want to do]

Can this be done? I find it somewhat hard to explain what exactly do I want to do, so I can update this question to clarify. I'm using Excel 2013 if that makes any difference.

Comment: Welcome to SU. Have you looked at [What-If Analysis](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Introduction-to-what-if-analysis-22bffa5f-e891-4acc-bf7a-e4645c446fb4) in Data Tools? Also, for us to help you, we need to know more about the data set you are trying to study.